# mysql_connect not working in a server over a VPN

Tags: php, mysql, vpn

My `"mysql_pconnect() / connect()`"` function doesn't work on a server over a VPN.
I used the VPN to access the server where in there I created a PHP website. When I run my website it's a blank page. I was wondering why  it is a blank page, so I find the error, now the error is the database connection. but it's just the same with my localhost, and the website on my localhost is working. but when I transfer my website to the server it's not working. is there something to do with the VPN? My user and pass to connect to the mysql is correct.

main.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$settings_dir = "./settings";
require_once("$settings_dir/database2.php");
//etc etc codes..
```

database2.php

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","passw0rd");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because you cant give the same arguments to `mysql_pconnect()` which you gave in case of your localhost.because where you hosted your website,there u will have diffrent server name ,DBname and DB password.

```
mysqli_connect(server,user,pwd,newlink,clientflag)
```

here the first argument is server which is the hostname,in case of local server its localhost but when you are using any remote server than u need to specify that server name.similarly `username` and `password` will be different for that server.

read here

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: i have same dbname. is it the server name is "localhost"? then should i change it right?

Comment: i updated my answer have a look,and better check for the server name in Cpanel also make sure about the username and password which also u will get in cpanel

Comment: well . even if i have a correct credentials, or wrong. it doesn't print any error. which is the mysql error connect function. it will only be a blank white page. :(

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost","root","passw0rd");
well this is an example. is it going to change if i put it in a server.. because in my localhost and server. the user and pass are the same.

Comment: write this in the beginning of your php file to know the errors error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);also i am pretty sure that the name of your remote server will not be localhost,but there might be some cases where the server name will be same .to avoid any confusion call the customer service from where u bought the server space.

Comment: check your servername :)

Comment: isn't localhost? . im sorry , im noob in server thingy. :( or 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Vincent what i meant is check the name of the host server where you are hosting your website.

Comment: ow. i think this is the name . "gw-server"   i type the hostname in my linux. gw-server is the result.

Comment: replace localhost with gw-server if you are sure.